# How can I do day timer with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, date, datetime, timer

I need timer with day. I want to change automatically rows at HTML tables every day.

For example; If day 11 or 12 or 25 and month February and hour 08 , change rows with "Hello!" .

```js
function time() {

  var xdate = new Date();
  var $second = xdate.getSeconds();
  var $minutes = xdate.getMinutes();
  var $hours = xdate.getHours();
  var $day = xdate.getDay();
  var $date = xdate.getDate();
  var $month = xdate.getMonth();
  var $year = xdate.getFullYear();

  console.log($date + "/" + $month + "---" + $hours + ":" + $minutes);
  setTimeout("time()", 1000);

  var x = document.getElementById("help1");

  if ($date == (11 || 12 || 25) && $month === 1 && $hours == 08) {
    document.getElementById("help1").innerHTML = "Hello"
  }
}
time();
```

```html
<span id="help1">Hi</span>
```

Comment: `if($date==(11||12||25)` - it does not work like that in JS. You either need to write this as three individual comparisons, joined by a logical OR - or you put those values into an array, and then you check if your date value is contained in that array using the appropriate array method.

Comment: I made you a snippet. I changed the TD which was invalid (there is not such thing as type on a td. And change zaman() to time()

Comment: Note that *setInterval* doesn't run at **exactly** the interval specified, so from time to time the clock will appear to skip a second, though it should display the correct time.

Answer (score 2):

You probably meant

```js
const pad = num => ("0"+num).slice(-2);
function time() {

  var xdate = new Date();
  var hours = xdate.getHours();
  var minutes = xdate.getMinutes();
  var seconds = xdate.getSeconds();
  var date = xdate.getDate();
  var month = xdate.getMonth()+1; // months start at 0
  var year = xdate.getFullYear();

  x.innerHTML = date + "/" + pad(month) + "---" + pad(hours)+":"+pad(minutes)+":"+pad(seconds);
  
  // day 11 or 12 or 25 and month February and hour 8 
  
  if ((date === 11 || date === 12 || date === 25) && month === 2 && hours === 8) {
    x.innerHTML = "Hello"
    // clearInterval(tId); // this will stop the timer
  }
}
var x, tId;
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
  x = document.getElementById("help1");
  tId = setInterval(time,1000);
});
```

```html
<span id="help1"></span>
```

Comment: hi master :)
I tried everything but I could not ...
I 'll try again again..